# Why styles don't update when saving the files in Tailwind CSS JIT mode and I need to restart the server?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Edit: **This issue is now deprecated since version 3.0.0 of tailwind works with react without having to use CRACO**.

While trying to use Tailwind with React in JIT mode the classes that I add have no styles, even after refreshing the page. I have to restart the server for the styles to take effect.

tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "jit",
    purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
    ...
}
```

craco.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    style: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")]
        }
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "random-name",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@craco/craco": "^6.3.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "craco start",
        "build": "craco build",
        "test": "craco test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.17",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
        "postcss": "^7.0.39",
        "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

As of **Tailwind v3.0+** JIT mode is now a [built-in feature](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode).

> In Tailwind CSS v3.0, the new engine has gone stable and replaced the
> classic engine, so every Tailwind project can benefit from these
> improvements out of the box.

---

### Old Answer

This seems to be a common issue when using tailwind JIT mode and it's explained in [troubleshooting guides](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#styles-don-t-update-when-saving-content-files).

> As of Tailwind CSS v2.2+, the JIT engine depends on PostCSS’s
> directory dependency messages to register your content files as CSS
> build dependencies with your build tool. These are a fairly new
> addition to PostCSS (added in May 2021), and not all build tools have
> been updated to support them yet.
>
> If your CSS isn’t rebuilding when you change your content files, try
> setting `TAILWIND_MODE=watch` as part of your watch script to tell
> Tailwind to use a legacy dependency tracking strategy instead, which
> works well with many build tools.

Since [CRACO](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) is used to configure tailwind CSS for React.js , add this to your `package.json` file.

```
{
  // ...
  scripts: {
    "dev": "TAILWIND_MODE=watch craco start",

    // Do not set TAILWIND_MODE for one-off builds
    "build": "craco build",
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

Also, please note that

> You should only set TAILWIND_MODE=watch when you are actually running
> a dev server/watch process, and only if your build tool doesn’t yet
> support PostCSS directory dependency messages. **This flag is a
> temporary workaround for incompatible tooling, and will eventually be
> removed in a future version of Tailwind CSS.**

Answer (score 1):

In `package.json` you should activate watch mode on the start script like

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "TAILWIND_MODE=watch craco start",
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `package.json` for the `posctcss` version. When I installed Tailwind it was version 7 and I had the same problem. I just updated my `postcss` to the latest version and it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem resolved when I installed "PostCSS Language Support". Give that a try! :)